# Getting warning that a component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled while trying to Pass empty array to Autocomplete component-MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, single-page-application

I am new to react and material UI and struggling to load Autocomplete component options dynamically.

Initially, I am setting empty array as initial option until data is fetched from the database. Once I get my data I update the  Autocomplete options with my data and it's working but at the same time I am getting the following warning

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

**My code**

```
const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([]);

    const {formik, items} = props;

    const handleGetOptionSelected = (option, value) => {
        if (!items) {
            return {};
        }
        return option.id === value.id;
    };

    const handleGetOptionLabel = (option) => {
        if (!items) {
            return 'No Options';
        }
        return option.name;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (items) {
            setListItems(items);
        }
    }, [items]);

return (

        <Autocomplete
            className={classes.autoComplete}
            multiple
            id="tags-standard"
            options={listItems}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => handleGetOptionLabel(option)}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => handleGetOptionSelected(option, value)}
            onChange={(event, selectedValues) => {
                formik.setFieldValue(
                    "tag_ids",
                    getCollectionColumn(selectedValues, 'id'),
                    false
                );
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant="standard"
                    placeholder="select tags"
                    name="tag_ids"
                    error={formik.touched.tag_ids && Boolean(formik.errors.tag_ids)}
                    helperText={formik.touched.tag_ids && formik.errors.tag_ids}
                />
            )}
        />

    );
```

Comment: What is getCollectionColumn inside onChange and what's its use?

Comment: getCollectionColumn is my own custom function to get column value from array of objects. Btw onchange handler is never called

Comment: Initialize the object structure as empty string then change it on onChange will likely fix the issue.